# Missing first element from list output in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, ord

I am a beginner in Haskell and I am missing a concept while using Ord. I am trying to unique pairs out of a list in Haskell through the function below

```
pairs:: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs[] = []
pairs(x:xs) = [(i, j) | i <- xs, j <- xs, i > j]
```

So for example if i want to get the unique pairs of [4,3,1,2] i should get the output
[(4,3),(4,1),(4,2),(3,1),(3,2),(2,1)]

but I am getting [(3,1),(3,2)] instead.

my question is, why is this skipping the first element of the list xs?

Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense: where do you use `x` here in your second clause.

Comment: Enabling warnings would report that `x` is defined by never used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, why is this skipping the first element of the list `xs`?

It is not skipping the first element of the list `xs`. It is just skipping `x`. `(x:xs)` is a pattern where `x` is the "head" of the list (the first item), whereas `xs` is the *tail* of the list (a list containing the remaining elements).

You thus likely want to use:

```
pairs:: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs xs = [(i, j) | i <- xs, j <- xs, i > j]
```

Here we thus capture the entire list `xs`.

If the order does not matter much, we can make this a bit more efficient by calculating the minimum and maximum, and iterating over the tails:

```
import Data.List(tails)

order2 :: Ord a => a -> a -> (a, a)
order2 x y | x > y = (x, y)
           | otherwise = (y, x)

pairs:: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs xs = [order2 i j | (i:js) <- tails xs, j <- js, i /= j]
```

Here we thus first take an element `i`, and the remaining elements are stored in `js`. We then iterate over `js`. If `i` and `j` are not the same, we use `order2` to create a 2-tuple where the first item is larger than the second item.